# Error Cannot find module 'angular'

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am trying to migrate Angular 1 to Angular 2 with the guide of https://ngthailand.gitbooks.io/ngcourse2-in-thai/content/handout/migrate/ng-upgrade/upgrade-component.html
When I run using **npm start** it shows error **Cannot find module 'angular'**

This is my **systemjs.config.js**

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'

  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' }

  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

How to solve this??

Comment: are you migrating to angular 2 rc5??

Comment: if you use angular2 beta then you should map to angular2 i.e., `'angular2':                   'node_modules/angular2'` instead of `@angular`

Answer (score 0):

Create `package.json` file and paste below content into it:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.15",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

and make sure to run the command `npm install`

Hope it solves you problem :)

Comment: Still i am getting same problem

Comment: do you have folder named node_modules after running npm install command

Comment: https://angular.io/resources/live-examples/quickstart/ts/plnkr.html, this is a plunker of official quickstart guide from angular.io, compare your project with it

Comment: Given plunker is fine for Angular2, but i need to migrate angular1.x to angular2. I am just replicating the above mentioned link in my question. but its not working.

Comment: first make a quickstart project in angular 2, it will help you in migration.

Comment: Or if you want i will fix it for you, if you manage to give a plunker of your app with above error

Comment: this is what i tried.. i dont know whether i am using this right.. [http://plnkr.co/edit/Ns5N1QdWHvq5EYLd3DSB?p=preview]